# What if IEnumerable<string> returns just one string

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, linq, ienumerable

I'm doing a simple Linq query on an XML file

```
IEnumerable<string> value = from item in myFile.Descendants("ProductName")
                            select (string)item;
```

Normally (If I have more than one row) I can iterate using a foreach loop :

```
foreach (string str in value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

But what if I'm sure that I have just one item, And my method signature is :

```
public string getValue()
{
    return ?;
}
```

What should I return (If I want to **remove** the **foreach** loop) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357287) / [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494540) and [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356424) / [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358452) methods that can resolve an enumerable of elements down to one.

The `Single` method ***expects*** only one element and will exception if the result contains zero or more than one elements. Use `SingleOrDefault` to cope with zero as well as one.

The "First" pair can both handle more than one, but `First` again throws if there are no elements.

All of these methods come with an overload that allows you to specify conditions, negating the need to use a `.Where` call.

In your case:

```
string value = (from item in myFile.Descendants("ProductName")
                select (string)item)
               .SingleOrDefault();
```

When choosing between Single or First, use `Single` if you expect one element, use `SingleOrDefault` if you expect zero or one elements, and use `First` / `FirstOrDefault` (along with some sort of `OrderBy`) if you don't care how many elements are returned.

Also note, these methods use deferred execution, so once `First` is satisfied it stops iterating.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that there is always exactly one string, you can return `value.Single()`.

Some more options:

- [First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first)
- [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)
- [SingleOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault)

It depends if you want to raise an exception if there are more than one element (use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault`), or no element at all (use `First` or `Single`).

If you always except exactly one element, I would stick with [Single()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single), since it will throw an exception if there are zero or more than one element.

Comment: Thank you @BigYellowCactus for your response, but I choosed Adam Houldsworth because he gived an example of code and the best explanation fot this situation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return only one item, then use [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx):

```
public string getValue()
{
    IEnumerable<string> value = from item in myFile.Descendants("ProductName")
                        select (string)item;
    return value.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have only one and must be only one you should use `Single` .
This actually will throw an exception if you have more than one.